# Add xml value to the body tag as a class using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm very rusty with xsl so I'll try and ask this question as best I can but what I'm trying to do is get the value of my XML file attribute in this case "pharmacy" and pass that as a class to the body tag in my xsl file. I ended up using jQuery which works but is what I asking possible using xsl?

My jQuery solution:

```
<script>                
          $(function() {
            var a =  $('.cohort').text();
          $('body').removeClass('no-js').addClass('je-enabled ' + a)                                        
             });              
</script>
```

My XSL:

```
<xsl:template match = "/">              
    <html> 
     <body class="no-js"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates /> 
     </body> 
    </html> 
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="COURSE">
 <div class="cohort sr-only"><xsl:value-of select="@STUDY_AREA"/></div>
 .
 .
</xsl:template>
```

My XML

```
<COURSES>
  <COURSE id="1" STUDY_AREA="pharmacy">
  .
  .
  </COURSE>
</COURSES>
```

Your help would be appreciated - sorry if I didn't add the full code because its massive - hope what I have provided is sufficient.

Comment: Didn't you ask this question before? And didn't I ask you how to identify the COURSE from which you want to copy the value?

Comment: Hey Micheal, no you didn't, just said not enough info - I thought better to retry or reword the question - does it still not make sense - have I not provided enough info? I have had a look to try and find a solution but anything I have found is deprecated.

Comment: It's a simple question: if you have more than one course (as I am sure you do), which course's study area do you want to copy to the body?

Comment: The end result will only show 1.  I'm guessing some variable gets passed? i.e <body class="no-js {my_value}"> Am I on the right track?

Comment: If you don't know, how am I supposed to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you want to:

- Read the content of `STUDY_AREA` attribute from `COURSE` tag,
  located in `COURSES` root tag (the class name).
- Generate `body` tag with `class` attribute equal to what you
  have just read, using `xsl:attribute`.

Then your template should look like below:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:attribute name="class" select="COURSES/COURSE/@STUDY_AREA"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Notice that:

- This template does not assign any class to the `body` tag
  in a static way.
- Instead it sets the `class` attribute with the target class name.

Comment: OMG! YES and YES! to answer your questions - how simple was that in the end  - Valdi_Bo to the rescue :-) I did however had to do this in the end <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="COURSES/COUR/@STUDY_AREA"/></xsl:attribute>